# Why is an ARN for an S3 bucket invalid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, identity-management

Sorry if a basic question but very new to AWS: Essentially I am following a tutorial and creating permissions for an S3 Bucket for a Ruby on Rails App.

The first ARN I created is fine no issues:

`arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon`

However, the tutorial then says to create another ARN so as access all files using the * wildcard like this:

`arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon/*`

However, when I try to do this I get the "Entered ARN is invalid." message?

I am trying to work around this but so far no luck - as I say brand new to AWS.

For full context the JSON view of my policy editor looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could anyone please advise how I can alter the `arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon/*` to be valid or else add the equivalent to the JSON?

Comment: the arn is fine for object level permissions, but it is not valid for s3:ListBucket, you need to split up your permissions or use both arns see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-policy-language-overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some API calls (eg `ListBucket`) operate on the **bucket** and therefore need permission on

```
arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon
```

Some API calls (eg `GetObject`) operate on objects and therefore need permission on:

```
arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon/*
```

Those ones can even be restricted to certain paths, such as:

```
arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon/public/*
```

This grants permission on any objects with a path that starts with `public/`.

You could therefore supply two different statements:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it is typically easier to combine them into one statement:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon",
                "arn:aws:s3:::learning-path-blog-jon/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```